# In Excel how to get the left 5 characters of each cell in a specified column and put them into a new column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to take the left 5 characters of each cell in column E and put them into the adjoining cell in column F:

```
A...B....C...D......E..................F
123.bb...cc..dd.....90210ABCE13........90210
555.bb...cc..dd.....10056Z19s..........10056
```

Using Left(x, 5) function, how does Excel say "do this to every cell in the specified column"?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

1) Put `=Left(E1,5)` in `F1`

2) Copy `F1`, then select entire `F` column and paste.

Comment: I'm not sure of the formula. What is 'x' in `Left(x,5`)?  And which column gets selected, the source column or the target column?

Comment: Thanks for this. Is it possible to take skip the first two letters and just add the second three?

Comment: @the_prole Yes, there is a `MID` function for that

Answer (score 1):

I find, if the data is imported, you may need to use the trim command on top of it, to get your details.
=LEFT(TRIM(B2),8)
In my case, I was using it to find a IP range.  10.3.44.44 with mask 255.255.255.0, so response is: 10.3.44
Kind of handy.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the "auto-fill" in Excel?

If you have an entire column of items you put the formula in the first cell, make sure you get the result you desire and then you can do the copy/paste, or use auto fill which is an option that sits on the bottom right corner of the cell.

You go to that corner in the cell and once your cursor changes to a "+", you can double-click on it and it should populate all the way down to the last entry (as long as there are no populated cells, that is).